# How keep running springboot webapp jar as background using jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jar

(Jenkins Version 2.414.1)

I am trying to run a simple Java spring-boot web-app jar file using Jenkins(Freestyle project) that will be running on port 8080, but Jenkins Finished: SUCCESS the job but my app are not running.

my Execute shell command is:

```
cd /opt/jenkins_WORKSHOP
echo "Application running............"
nohup java -jar spring-boot-simple-web.jar &
```

I am pretty sure that jenkins started app and after that kills the process Jenkins self.

How ..?

When I run this with a sleep command, the app keeps running until sleep time is over!

```
cd /opt/jenkins_WORKSHOP
echo "Application running............"
nohup java -jar spring-boot-simple-web.jar &
sleep 10
```

Now my question is how I can run my spring-web-app jar file in the background using Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins does some process cleanup after the job completes. You can read [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). To disable it you need to change the marker environment variable Jenkins is looking for - `BUILD_ID` for freestyle.

```bash
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup java -jar spring-boot-simple-web.jar &
```